# Springboot Requestmapper Regexpression

Tags: regex, spring-boot, subdirectory, request-mapping

In my Springboot-Controller my Requestmapping method should support flexible subdirectory names. For that I like to use real regexpression. I have tested my regex and it **works fine** outside of SpringBoot and RequestMapping, however on top of RequestMapping it does not work.

If  any http-requests gets in with

`http://dir1` or `http://dir2`

my Method getFile should be called, but it doesn't.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{reg:\\/(dir1|dir2)+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)    
public void getFile(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest requ) throws IOException {

}
```

My question is how to accomplish this ....

Comment: I guess you want to recover the path inside the method? So you are probably  better off with something like  `@RequestMapping(value = "/{dir}", ...) public File getFile(@PathVariable("dir") String directory,...)`

Comment: Thank you Dirk (German?). I also think that I have to recover the path inside the method. As I wrote to Jayanthi I am looking for any line of documentation that confirms, that multiple path-values via regex are not supported by RequestMapping.

Comment: you can use regex in combination with PathVariable like  `@GetMapping("/{reg:[dir1|dir2]+}")` as long your 'dir' does not contain a '/'

Answer (score 1):

The regex-based @RequestHandler can be achieved through ([for more](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping#3-pathvariable-with-regex))

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "{reg:regexPattern}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
            @PathVariable String reg) throws IOException {
                 ...
             }
```

But in your case, the regex pattern is a directory value that contains Slash("/") makes request handler difficult to find the exact mapping. Instead of `@PathVariable`, you can use `@RequestParam`

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "\", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
          @RequestParam("dir") String dir) throws IOException {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but in my case this does not really help me, while the Request is fix an cannot transfer any parameter. I haven't read any line in any documentation, that the regex does not support my subdirectory-path problem.

Comment: @LikeTomAndJerry in your case `@GetMapping("/{reg:[dir1|dir2]+}")` in combination with `@PathVariable String reg`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is (Dirk Deyne gave me the hint) that the Slashes have to be outside the regexpression. Here is the solution, where I have extended the value with another subdir **filedir** to make it more clear:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{subdir:[dir1|dir2]+}/filedir", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getFile(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest requ) {
  ...
}
```

This will serve the following incoming requests:

- http://localhost:8080/**dir1**/filedir
- http://localhost:8080/**dir2**/filedir

Thank you!